# Progress HUD showing too late

Tags: ios, objective-c, preloader

I am currently loading a new view dynamically by evaluating the `segue.identifier` in the `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"DetailViewSegue"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailController = segue.destinationViewController;
        // ... do something with the controller
    }
}
```

Some of those views need a bit of time because gathering the data from the Internet and displaying that in a table scheme needs a rather long time.
Therefore I want to display a Progress HUD like `KVNProgress`, however the main issue now is that the Progress bar shows up too late, right before the new view is ready. As far as I have seen is the main Problem, that the `prepareForSegue` method and therefore the `KVNProgress` was called immediately before loading all the data, but loading a new view seems to be preferred instead.

Another thing I tried was to call `KVNProgress` within a `IBAction` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and to call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` within his own thread. However this is (as the console output suggests) discouraged, and does not really work either.

Thanks!

EDIT:
There were multiple attempts achieving this, currently I am trying to do it that way:

```
(IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender {
    [KVNProgress showWithStatus:@"Loading"];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

As I've described, i think this is the earliest I can display the ProgressHUD before the new action is loaded. However it seems that the current view is blocked while the new one is loaded, and therefore the hud is not shown.

Comment: Where's the code for showing the progress HUD?

Comment: Where do you show the HUD?

Comment: Are you trying to show the progress hud and collect the data before showing the new view?  If so you should do that in response to some other event (such as a user tap?) and perform the segue once you have finished gathering the data.  Otherwise show the hud and gather the data in the target view controller after the segue.

Comment: thank you for the feedback - I hope my edit above clears that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this.

When the user taps on a "Load data" button,

- you display the HUD  (and stay on the current screen)
- load the datafrom the internet  (typically on a background thread)
- when it's complete, you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` to move to the DetailView screen

Alternatively, you might prefer to do this:

- you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` as soon as the user taps the
  button
- you move to the new DetailView screen
- in the DetailViewController.m, you display the HUD and call the
  background thread to load the internet data

There's pros and cons to both  (you might find the latter is more maintainable, as other screens call this `DetailView` screen and also need to load the internet data to populate this screen).

The key is to decide which way you want to implement this, then get *that particular* ViewController to do both parts, handling the HUD *and* loading the internet data.

Comment: I just implemented this approach and it worked, however loading now is really slow (compared to previous): In my `viewDidLoad`i started the `KVNProgress` and than a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ /** do something  and set table delegate and dismiss KVNProgress **/ })`. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Loading cannot be slower, one way or the other.  And I would put this code in viewDidAppear, rather than viewDidLoad.  Give iOS a chance to finish displaying your screen, before kicking off the data load...

Comment: you are totally correct, by placing parts of that logic (those to display the `KVNProgress`) to `viewWillAppear` and other parts to `viewDidAppear` (those lines who loads and displays the data), everything is fine! Thank You!